# PHP cookie not working right after setting it

Tags: php, cookies

I am new to cookies, and tried to search for my problem, but couldn't find it.

My code:

index.php

```
<?php 
   if (isset($_GET["submit"])) {
       setcookie("time",date('Y/m/d H:i:s'),time()+3600);

       echo $_COOKIE["time"];
   }

   //Look if cookie isset, if not open overlay.
   if (isset($_COOKIE["time"])) {
      echo "<body>";
   } else {
       echo "<body onload='toggleOverlay(0)'>";
    }
?>
```

When you open the page in the browser, the bottom part of the php code is executed, there shouldn't be a cookie 'time' so the body will be echoed with the onload="toggleoverlay()". This all works fine.

then when i click on the submit button to accepts the cookies, the page is reload, and the upper part of my php code is executed, a cookie named 'time' is created with the current time.

then the bottom part should be executed, but it still echos the body with the onload, even though i just created the cookie.

i also get the error when i'm trying to echo the cookie (saying the cookie does not exist). when i reload the page again manually then it works. But this is very frustrating since you need to accepts the cookie. then the page gets reloaded, and the overlay opens again.

I think this is because it takes some time creating the cookie and by then the other code has already been executed, but does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php: _“Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for.”_

Comment: Set a flag, at the moment when you are setting the cookie, `$did_just_set_cookie = true;`, and then in your condition check if either the cookie value was set, or this flag - `if (isset($did_just_set_cookie) || isset($_COOKIE["time"]))`

Comment: The flag is indeed better then my option of reloading the page again with php, thanks

Comment: Or, you can of course also just do `$_COOKIE["time"] = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');` (or just `1` or `true`, if the specific value does not matter) - that array is writable, so you could just put the value you just set with `setcookie` and that would normally just become available in $_COOKIE only after the next request, in there yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie is not set until the response is sent back to the client (browser). It is not available in your PHP until the next request from the client after that.

You could do next.

```
<?php
    $cookie_set = isset($_COOKIE['time']);

    if (!$cookie_set && isset($_GET['submit']) {
        setcookie('time', date('Y/m/d H:i:s'), time() + 3600);
        $cookie_set = true;
    }

    if ($cookie_set) {
        echo '<body>';
    } else {
        echo '<body onload="toggleOverlay(0)">';
    }
```

Comment: This does work on first glance, but when the page is reloaded with another get parameter the overlay will appear again because the $cookie_set will be false againg

shouldn't the bottom if statement be:  if($cookie_set || $_COOKIE["time"])

But thanks for the answer

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a semi-solution, if the page is submitted, the page is reloaded, then after the cookie is created, i reload the page again en change the index.php?submit to index.php

like this

```
 <?php 
   if (isset($_GET["submit"])) {
     setcookie("time",date('Y/m/d H:i:s'),time()+3600);

     echo $_COOKIE["time"];

     header("Refresh:0; url=index.php");
   }

   //Look if cookie isset, if not open overlay.
   if (isset($_COOKIE["time"])) {
      echo "<body>";
   } else {
      echo "<body onload='toggleOverlay(0)'>";
  }
?>
```

Like this it works, but it is not the best solution.

Comment: Check my answer to understand why you face the problem.